# Accessing private members with GoogleTest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, private-members

I'm having trouble friending to access private members. Here is my code.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef TEST_FRIENDS
#define TEST_FRIENDS
#endif

namespace LibToTestNamespace
{
    class LibToTest
    {
    public:
        double Add(double, double);

    private:
        TEST_FRIENDS;
        int GetMyInt();
        int mInt;
    };
}
```

and

```
#include "UnitTests.h"
#define TEST_FRIENDS \
    friend class TestCustomUnitTest_hello_Test;
#include "LibToTest.h"

TEST(TestCustomUnitTest, hello)
{
    LibToTestNamespace::LibToTest ltt;
    ltt.mInt = 5;
    ltt.GetMyInt();
}
```

I get errors "cannot access private member declared in class". I'm thinking the lib gets built first so TEST_FRIENDS isn't getting replaced correctly? But if the unit test depends on the library, it will always get built first right?

Comment: As for what the macro is at a particular spot, You can always look at the preprocessed output by using the `-E` flag.   I recommend putting the TEST_FRIENDS definition in a single place and having it depend on a `-DTESTING` flag or something that is only defined on your test builds

Comment: When unit testing you should not have to access private members. You should be exercising the public interface

Comment: @user4581301 some people say that, other people disagree with it.  It's not a universally accepted truth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this to work by wrapping my Unit test class in the same namespace that my production class existed in.

```
namespace LibToTestNamespace
{
    TEST(TestCustomUnitTest, hello)
    {
        LibToTest ltt;
        ltt.mInt = 5;
        ltt.GetMyInt();
    }
}
```